# Responsive html table with staking cells

Tags: html-table

I have 4x3 html table with headers and footers. I want all table cells have same size and height. And stacking table cells depends on screen size. Thanks in advance.
eg. for large screen table format is

Header
col1 col2 col3
col4 col5 col6
col7 col8 col9
Footer

For medium screen ,
Header
col1 col2
col3 col4
col5 col6
col7 col8
col9
Footer

For small screen,
Header
col1
col2
.
.
.
col9
Footer

Comment: Show us the code that you did so far

Comment: how can i paste code in stack overflow?

Comment: Edit your post and paste code and use ctrl+k for indentation